# How to save value in SharedPeference in the actitvity and access it all other classes

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I want to save totalBalance in this activity to SharedPreferances and the retrive it in another class.

so i want totalbalance to be displayed in another activities in same application...
if possible also edit it in other activites...

please help... thanks

```
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Do something in response to button click

            // Genrating random number Random number
            Random rn = new Random();
            randomNumber = (int) rn.nextInt(9) + 1;

            // changes textView1 equals to random number
            textView1.setText("Random Number is "
                    + Integer.toString(randomNumber));
            button1.setText("Play Again");

            // Matching random number to ArrayList
            if (positive_IDs.contains(randomNumber)) {
                // if matched then changes textView2 to Matched Number
                textView2.setText("Number: "
                        + Integer.toString(randomNumber) + " Matched");

                totalBalance = totalBalance + winingPrize;
                textView5.setText("Total Balance = Rs: "
                        + String.format("%.2f", totalBalance));



            }

        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this,

```
public  void saveValue(String lock, Context context) {
    Editor editor = context
            .getSharedPreferences(KEY, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.putString("Value", lock);
    editor.commit();
}

public  String getValue(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences savedvalue = context.getSharedPreferences(KEY,
            Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return savedvalue.getString("Value", "");

}
```

Comment: Your getYourValue is flawed, it always get the value of MINUTE.

Answer (score 4):

Save Value as Following

```
 int Value;
    private void saveValues(){
    SharedPreferences readSP = getSharedPreferences("String", MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = readSP.edit();
            editor.putString("String", Value);
            editor.commit();
    }
```

Retrive value in any of your Class As following

```
int value;


private void getSavedValue()
{
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("String", MODE_PRIVATE);
value=settings.getString("String", "");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use following code to retrive your value from SharedPreference,write this in other class where you want to retrive value of total balance

```
 SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(YourActivityName.this);

Editor edit1 = remembermepref.edit();
            edit1.putInt("totalbalance_key",totalBalance);
            edit1.commit();
```

and to store total balance into ShardPreference use in your activity:

```
SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(YourActivityName.this);
int totalbalance = pref.getInt("totalbalance_key");
```

Now use totalbalance way you want. 
    Most important thing is to check whether you have used same key to restore as well as    tostore the value in SharedPreference

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 1):

```
// try this
 SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("yourSharePreferenceName", MODE_PRIVATE);
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
 editor.putBoolean("balance", String.format("%.2f", totalBalance));
 editor.commit();

 SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("yourSharePreferenceName", MODE_PRIVATE);
 String total = sharedPreferences.getString("balance");
```